# CXF 3.0.1 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.getHeaderString

Tags: spring, cxf, tomcat8

We are using CXF 3.0.1 with Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE and tomcat 8.0.36. Below is the POM defintion. We are getting this "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.getHeaderString" error whenever a HTTP GET call is invoked. Please let us know what is wrong here.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.aha.sdp.product</groupId>
<artifactId>aha-sdp-ws-product</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>aha-sdp-ws-product Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>

    <spring.data.version>1.8.0.RELEASE</spring.data.version>

    <!-- For Spring's JDBCTemplate -->
    <spring.jdbc.version>4.1.8.RELEASE</spring.jdbc.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <cxf.version>3.0.1</cxf.version>
    <swagger.version>1.5.12</swagger.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.0</jackson.version>

    <buildNumber>DEFAULT_BUILD_NUMBER</buildNumber>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aha.sdp</groupId>
        <artifactId>aha-sdp-ws-common</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit-coverage</artifactId>
        <version>0.999.22</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-RC2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>aha-sdp-ws-product</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Version>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>jmockit-coverage-excludes</name>
                        <value>com.aha.entity.*</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <threshold>Low</threshold><!-- High|Normal|Low|Exp|Ignore -->
                <effort>Default</effort><!-- Min|Default|Max -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Normally, we take off the dependency report, saves time. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>



    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue today with spring 4.3.3-RELEASE, updating CXF to version 3.1.0 or higher will sort the problem.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

The method getHeaderString is inside HttpHeadersImpl

Answer (score 0):

As this issue reported here long back but It may help others if they are facing the same issue.

I got the same issue and resolved with this approach  :-

Check in your application, there should be some other jars which has "HttpHeaders.getHeaderString". You can exclude those jar if you can, else change the jar declaration sequence in pom.xml. So that "cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs" load first in class path.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue. The problem was fixed after updating Maven to the latest version.